# How can I test if a function returns a message

Tags: r, selenium, message, rselenium

**BACKGROUND:** In R the package "testit" ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testit/index.html)) has both the functions `has_warning` and `has_error` but I'm looking for a function that returns a logical TRUE/FALSE if **has_message**.

**WHY**: to identify when a `webElem$submitElement()` from the `RSelenium` package returns an RSelenium message since the selenium messages are not classified as warnings or errors in R.

**Is there a way to test if a function returns a message at all in R?**

Ideally something like below:

```
#Ideally a function like this made up one:
has_message(message("Hello ","World!"))
[1] TRUE

has_message(print("Hello World!"))
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch`:

```
has_message <- function(expr) {
  tryCatch(
    invisible(capture.output(expr)),
    message = function(i) TRUE
  ) == TRUE
}

has_message(message("Hello World!"))
# TRUE
has_message(print("Hello World!"))
# FALSE
has_message(1)
# FALSE
```

Evaluate expression within `tryCatch` with `invisible(capture.output())` to suppress `print` or other output. We need final `== TRUE` to return `FALSE` when no message was present, otherwise for the last to examples there would be no output.